# How to make arduino GPIO to operate at 3.3v instead of default 5v

Tags: arduino, voltage, bluetooth, step-down

I am working on a project, I use arduino mega 2560 with system operating voltage of 5v, at the same time I have a Bluetooth module which operates at 3.3v is there any way to reduce my arduino output voltage without any external component such as resistor, ic etc
I saw the following statement in arduino website but couldn't understand, 
"IOREF. This pin on the Arduino board provides the voltage reference with which the microcontroller operates. A properly configured shield can
read the IOREF pin voltage and select the appropriate power source or enable voltage translators on the outputs for working with the 5V or
3.3V."

Comment: See http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/132/what-are-the-aref-ioref-and-the-unlabeled-pin-next-to-ioref-on-the-uno-r3

Comment: I think the IOREF pin will just be at 5V in your case and a shield with a BT module would sense that and levelshift for you. But you use a separate module.
From 5V to 3.3 V you can indeed use resisors. But if you have any signals going from 3.3 to 5V (and I think you do you also want to receive data from the BT module) then you need a "levelshifter", something like: http://www.ebay.nl/itm/5V-auf-3-3V-IIC-I2C-Logic-Level-Konverter-Bidirektionale-Modul-fur-Arduino-Neu-/251752724158?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_77&hash=item3a9da1b6be  might do the job.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AVR 2560 output are not 3V3 tolerant (for input) and you cannot internally change voltage level (output) unless you reduce Vcc to 3V3 (which reduces max. crystal frequency). You need employ level shifters. I prefer `74LVC125`, `74HCT125` ICs.

Comment: Thank you for the feed back, I guess I have to use a level shifter

Comment: +1 This is the best solution. I suggest avoiding level shifter chips that claim to automatically switch direction.